# Passing JSON file in Postgres with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

```
connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=db1 user=postgres password=postgres")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("set search_path to public")

with open('json_template') as file:
    data = file.read()

query_sql = """
insert into table1 select * from
json_populate_recordset(NULL::table1, %s);
"""

# change .execute(query_sql) to .execute(query_sql, (data,))
cursor.execute(query_sql, (data,))
connection.commit()
```

So I am trying to pass the contents of "json_template.json" to a Postgres table, but when I do I get the this error:
**psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue: cannot call json_populate_recordset on an object**

I've created the table through psql cmd. Also, here are the contents of my **json_template** file:

`{"key": "A123", "value": "15.6", "ts":"2020-10-07 13:28:43.399620+02:00"}`
Attaching screenshot: [json_template.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgf04.png).

Did some research on the error, however nothing came out. Also tried to rewrite the code *in other fashion* several times  - still the same error.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error: `psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue: cannot call json_populate_recordset on an object` has the information you need. You cannot pass in a  JSON object. And if you read the docs [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) you find that it needs an array of objects.

Comment: What is the data type of the target column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a `JSON object`, so you need to use `json_populate_record` instead of `json_populate_recordset`, which works for an array of objects.

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(...)
cursor = con.cursor()

with open('json_template') as file:
    data = file.read()

query_sql = """
insert into table1 select * from
json_populate_record(NULL::table1, %s);
"""

cursor.execute(query_sql, (data,))
con.commit()
cursor.execute('select * from table1')
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Out:

```
[('A123', '15.6', '2020-10-07 13:28:43.399620+02:00')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just **changed** the JSON file from:

```
{"key": "A123", "value": "15.6", "ts":"2020-10-07 13:28:43.399620+02:00"}
```

To:

```
[
    {
        "key": "A128",
        "value": "15.6",
        "ts": "2020-10-07 13:28:43.399620+02:00"
    }
]
```

And it worked. Thank you all for the help!